# wordpress plugin development

Tags: wordpress

Does anybody know about a simple customizable wordpress plugin framework with the help of which i can build more frameworks rapidly ??.

Comment: Did you mean "build more plug-ins"? And what is wrong with built-in plugin support?

Comment: Title should be revised.

Answer (score 2):

There is no any plugin framework. And you don't need to build any. If you want to learn how to create WP plugins, just go and download some simple. See how they works, read docs. And viola.

Comment: ya did that. built my own too. but code seems too messed up for my own good. so i was just wondering if there is any kind of approach which i can follow in order to have a very good clean code base with wordpress plugins

Comment: You can follow whatever rules you want developing WP plugins. Just use WP api and all will be fine. What plugin structure will be - you decide. And there is no need in frameworks

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-links/ i got my first plugin up and running but im having problems with the readme.txt file. 
the installation and FAQ's section isnt formatting properly. 

any help on this ??

Comment: Read this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Readme_File
Also take any plugin on site and see how it's readme file is formatted by downloading plugin. Each plugin has it in root folder.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out:

- LMB^Box WordPress Plugin API
- GD Plugin Core
- Wordpress Plugin Framework Reloaded

Search for them at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/